# user system with social authentication in django

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication

I've read about a lot of different apps for django for integrating social authentication to django projects. But, I'm having some trouble understanding how this integration works

Does it extends the default USER models? Where do I find those kind of information in the applications?

I basically need a user system that has groups (for permission purposes). The user would be able to register using a common registration proccess or facebook. Will I be able to achieve that with any kind of application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called django-allauth. If you read their official documentation, it is pretty easy to follow. As per their instructions, you install the core app, and any other authentication you need (like facebook, oauth which google uses). Then, you have to go to facebook, get developers key, and add it to your django admin.

Basically, when somebody tries to login using facebook, the signin process sends the keys to facebook, and check if the user exists. If it does, then the authentication app creates user on the backend, just like a normal signin process. You can get javascript from facebook to make a login window.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you wrote 'normal signin process', you meant that ALL users would be stored in the same place? The ones registered thru facebook and the ones registered thru common registration? Will I be able to set groups and permissions? Will I be able to reference every single user by an ID, that will be unique independent on the registration process?

Comment: If you look at their source code: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py , it seems the procedure of logging in user is the same regardless of the method. As long as you have username and password, and are active in the backend, you can login. Take my perspective with a grain of salt, but, it seems you should be able to manage them as you would manage 'normal users'. It does not take much time at all; you can give a shot and see.

Comment: So, if the user register using facebook he will have to create an username and password?

Comment: No no. Facebook provides the username (or email), and the password. If the user is not in the system, the authentication app creates it. When the user tries to log in the next time, the app tries to match the authentication credentials. So, if the user is present, he is authenticated.